# Content-Type header value for PDFs for Azure OCR Read API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-bot-service

I am trying to call `/vision/v3.1/read/analyze` API with a PDF, but sending `Content-Type` header as `application/pdf` or `application/octet-stream` is giving an `InvalidImage` error. What should be the header value ? Any code sample that I can refer to ?

Comment: What are you exactly sending to the API?

Answer (score 0):

The supported Content-Types are `application/json`- analyze images from URL and `application/octet-stream` - analyze images from disk. I tried the [Read API reference](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-1-ga/operations/5d986960601faab4bf452005) and provided url for a pdf file. Confirmed using [Get Read Result](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-1-ga/operations/5d9869604be85dee480c8750) and works fine. Check out available code samples in [python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/python-hand-text), [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Vision-Python) and [c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp-hand-text), [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/tutorials/csharptutorial).